# How to select row based on condition in various column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data

```
Probe dumhead1 cond1 cond2 cond3
foo   dum1     1.5  3.2    3.0
bar   dum10    2.0  1.0    2.1
qux   dum22    0.4  2.3    2.2
```

What I want to do is for each `cond 1 ..3`
report the probe where the value is greater than `2.0`.

In reality the number of probe is around  20k.

Resulting this (done by hand):

```
> cond1
[1] "bar"
> cond2
[1] "foo" "qux"
> cond3
[1] "foo" "bar" "qux"
```

What's the way to do it? 
I'm stuck with this code ....
Done in for-loop way which is very slow.

```
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1484534/plain/",sep=" ",header="TRUE")
 nofprobe <- nrow(dat)
 #...to be added....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply()` to make more extensible:

```
apply(dat[,3:5],2,FUN=function(x)dat$Probe[x>=2])

# breaking down the function call:
apply(dat[,3:5],                      # the subset of columns to test
      2,                              # 2 means run apply() col-wise
      FUN=function(x)dat$Probe[x>=2]) # dat$Probe gives the levels
                                      # returns rows where val >=2 
                                      # for each column (passed by x)
```

**EDIT** updated to use `ddply()` from `plyr' package to set individual conditions:

```
    require(plyr)

    results<-ddply(dat,.(Probe),summarize,
          cond1=(cond1>=2),
          cond2=(cond2<2),
          cond3=(cond3>=0)
          )

    apply(results[,2:4],2,FUN=function(x)dat$Probe[x]) # this returns same format
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine, as it involves less typing, especially if the number of columns you are looking through for values > 2 is large.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer! Later how can I access the vector of each column (preferably in for-loop context). Later for each column (condition) I want to perform an operation.

Comment: Hi @neversaint updated to show how you can use ddply to return test vectors for 1 condition per row and then convert to the same return format.

Answer (score 1):

If there are just 3 cond columns, then this seems reasonable:

```
dat[dat$cond1 > 2, ]$Probe
dat[dat$cond2 > 2, ]$Probe
dat[dat$cond3 > 2, ]$Probe
```